# Floating DIVs add padding to the bottom

Tags: html, css

Having a strange issue with floating divs with background colours.

We've designed a div to mimic a banner functionality for a client. The banner can be aligned left/right of text or neither.

When the banner is not aligned, then the banner looks as it should. However, extra padding is added when the banner is floating left/right.

```
Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/ZSE93/
```

If you have any ideas, that'd be great. Or if you have any questions, I'll happily explain them.

Cheers

Comment: And what is your question ????

Comment: The question appears to be, how to prevent the extra padding from being inserted at the base of the div that is being floated to the right. I'm inspecting it now.

Comment: Yes, Marius that is correct. Sorry for not explaining it thoroughly, had a bit of a brain fog this morning :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's due to the `margin-bottom` on the inner p, below are two options to fix this

```
.banner p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

or

```
.banner p {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Last1Here/ZSE93/4/) showing the fix.

Comment: Well I feel a bit thick! Should've spotted that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this example

```
.banner{
  float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/5dgFv/